# What is the Best way to compare file signature to predefined signatures?

Tags: java, algorithm

I've a list of XML Files (700 files) that contain a File Signature record. I would like to test a given file against those list of signature records. What is the best way to store those XML Files to do fast comparison ?

2nd Problem: 
How do I detect a bad signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preprocess those files and create a dictionary mapping file signatures to filenames. Store it in a [hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html), [tree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) or other data structure with a fast lookup time, that is O(log n) or better. Then query the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest is to load all XML up into memory. 700 is a small number. Then, sort your signature if it is possible using linear or binary tree. Now, you can search your list. If it is binary tree, you can use binary search which is faster.